# Can't use node modules installed by NPM despite correct NODE_PATH on a Mac

Tags: node.js, osx-lion, npm

Running on OSX 10.7 (Lion).
Tried including as much detail here. I (foolishly?) decided to upgrade to the latest NODE and NPM. I git-ed and curl-ed like a good boy, and ended up with this:

```
>node -v
v0.5.9
>npm -v
1.0.99
```

added `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/lib/node` which yields:

```
>echo $NODE_PATH
/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/lib/node
```

But every `require` I have in all my scripts fails in finding any of my modules. It either looks in the local library, or just gives up with an "Error: Cannot find module" message.

I tried variations on the NODE_PATH: with/without the node_modules, with specific directories - nada.

Am I missing some NPM configuration? Am I using it incorrectly? All the scripts worked well prior to the upgrade.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved it by installing modules locally into the specific node directories.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate what you mean by "specific node directories"?

Meaning are they installed local to project or global path folders?

Comment: Meaning local to the project.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with modules installed using 'npm install -g'.  Yes, installing them locally works - but it would be nice to know why global modules can no longer be found.

Comment: It's almost a year later, and I still have a problem with global installation. I have no idea what system variable is missing. But since deployment to prod servers works better with local installations, I get by with local.