# -bash: <npm package> command not found

Tags: node.js, bash

I have been working on a site for several weeks, and just recently I ran into a problem. Now whenever I try to run gulp or JSPM, I get the following errors:

> -bash: gulp: command not found
>
> -bash: jspm: command not found

Uninstalling and reinstalling Node and NPM hasn't seemed to have helped. I've also installed both Gulp and JSPM globally just now, and still have the same issue.

I'm working on a Mac while a colleague of mine is using Windows. Using the same codebase, everything seems to be working for him fine in Windows.

In case it helps, here's what my $PATH looks like:
`/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:`

I'm happy to provide more details, although I'm not sure what other information would help.

Comment: What does `npm ls -g --depth=0` show?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this here for any googlers: for a Windows 10 user you need to add `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm` to your Path variable

- Right click on start, choose System
- Click Advanced System Settings on the left
- Under the Advanced tab select Environment Variables
- Find Path in the System Variables section, select it and then click Edit
- Click New and type in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- Restart your terminal, it should now recognize any modules you have installed globally

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814598/cant-use-node-modules-installed-by-npm-despite-correct-node-path-on-a-mac), and it seems to have fixed it.

Now my $PATH has `/Users/%USERPROFILE%/.node/bin` included in it.